# Updating monetary value from double(8,2) to decimal(10,2) - safe?

Tags: php, mysql, casting, primitive-types

I figured out I have stored my monetary values, in different currencies, as a double, and I have heard that it is bad practice to store monetary values as float or double.

Now I wish to migrate my database tables from a `Double(8,2)` to `Decimal(10,2)`. I have tried testing locally converting a column in one of my tables to this value, and it seems to be working without issues, but I just wanted to verify that this could not cause any unforeseen consequences.